# Is there a way to iterate or increment a counter with Puppet

Tags: puppet

I have 5 servers each with 32 calls to something like this:

```
postfix::instance { "ms1-01":
  instance_number => "01",
  ip              => "10.0.0.1"
}

postfix::instance { "ms1-02":
  instance_number => "02",
  ip              => "10.0.0.2"
}
```

Needless to say it's annoying when I have to change the IPs, which is frequent enough that I'd like to know of an alternative way to implement this.

The `postfix::instance` type creates a unique file in a directory (`/etc/postfix/ms/${instance_number}/main.cf`) so I can't use a template to do the iteration.

What would be the best solution here ?

Thanks.

Comment: Is the manifest get applied to the same server where you have all the instance_number/main.cf on a single server?

Comment: One manifest contains 32 calls to `postfix::instance`, for one server. On that server, this will create 32 different main.cf file.

Comment: Is instance_number consistently used as the last octet of the IP address?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6403457/116207

Comment: No, instance_number is not always the last octet. Typically I receive /27 blocks which last octet is 96, or 64, etc.